How to write geojson from a pyspark dataframe
I am trying to build geojson from a pyspark dataframe, avoiding geopandas/pandas as it results in a very slow process if using chunks or to break the cluster.
data_union_json_query = f"""
            SELECT
                id,
                partitiongroup,
                ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText(geom), 27700) AS geom
            FROM partition_to_process_view
            WHERE partitiongroup = {partition}
        """

        data_json_df = spark.sql(data_union_json_query )
        
        base_df = data_json_df.toPandas()

        # Create 'geometry' column from 'geom' column
        base_df['geometry'] = base_df['geom'].apply(wkt.loads)

        # Drop the 'geom' column
        base_df.drop(columns=['geom'], inplace=True)

        # Convert Pandas DataFrame to GeoPandas DataFrame
        my_geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(base_df, geometry='geometry', crs='EPSG:4326')
        my_geo_df.to_file(filename=(f's3://my-bucket/geojson-folder/myname-{folder}.geojson'), driver='GeoJSON')

I have tried to build the object in the query and hten pass it to wirte the json:
data_union_json_query =  f"""
    SELECT 
        to_json(named_struct(
            'type', 'Feature',
            'geometry', ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(st_setsrid(ST_GeomFromText(geom),27700),'epsg:4326')),
            'properties', to_json(named_struct(
                'id', id,'initial', initial, 'partitiongroup', partitiongroup
            ))
        )) AS feature
    FROM 
        partition_to_process_view
    WHERE 
        partitiongroup = '{partition}'
    """
    partitioned_df
    data_json_df = spark.sql(data_union_json_query )

    partition_to_process_df_single = data_json_df.coalesce(1)
    partition_to_process_df_single.write.format('json').save(f's3://my-bucket/geojson-folder/myname-{folder}.geojson')

but the json generated is wrongly build... thisis an example of one of the lines:
{"feature":"{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":\"{\\\"type\\\":\\\"MultiPolygon\\\",\\\"coordinates\\\":[[[[-0.18516516196157679,51.5360852773271],[-0.18516164723311473,51.53608736315101],[-0.1851585164663171,51.53608922111172],[-0.18511201584092754,51.536116378248416],[-0.1850780856654579,51.53613563666034],[-0.18507316717116615,51.536132413218766],[-0.18501309750305794,51.53608382402634],[-0.1849863606982785,51.53606252995922],[-0.18483699782606317,51.53594351529598],[-0.18485906011201242,51.53593261612965],[-0.18492778470475388,51.53589810543051],[-0.18493115400654628,51.53589641303024],[-0.18497655731709386,51.535933085203595],[-0.18505691392777024,51.5359972753997],[-0.18516516196157679,51.5360852773271]]]]}\",\"properties\":\"{\\\"id\\\":\\\"20045\\\",\\\"initial\\\":\\\"2\\\",\\\"partitiongroup\\\":1}\"}"}

I cannot find information in Apache sedona and cannot see anything to build geojson directly.

Are you using Sedona? If so, this works for Sedona <= 1.6.0: https://github.com/apache/sedona/issues/814
We recently added a native GeoJSON reader and writer for Spark so in the upcoming 1.6.1 release, interaction with GeoJSON will be a lot easier: https://github.com/apache/sedona/pull/1432
